# How can I override the MimeType with angular's $http service? (XMLHttpRequest.overrideMimeType())

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to port [this](http://jsperf.com/encoding-xhr-image-data/14) example to Angular. I want to use $http instead of a XMLHttpRequest object. The code does

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
```

How can I override the MimeType with angular's $http service?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, it's not possible, see this feature request:

[$http/$httpBackend support for overrideMimeType() #7669](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7669)

- component: $http
- type: feature
- frequency: low